# Washing machine 7kg and washing an item 2.5 kg

Tags: washing-machine, laundry

I have a 7kg washing machine. I also have a blanket that is about 2.5kg and can be washed in a washing machine (based on its labels and material).
I think that the blanket fits inside the drum but my question is when the washing starts due to the water the blanket absorbs, could it get so heavy that it could be a problem for the machine capability?
Or in general does the 7kg means items total up to 7kg regardless of how heavy the get when they get wet?
I am planning to have only the blanket in the washing machine during the cycle

Comment: Is it what you would a big or tiny machine?.  With a big machine would say the weight of cloths.  7kg is about 15lbs so a decent size load.

Comment: what is a 7 kg washing machine?

Comment: afaik, that limit is a dry weight. it will spin out extra water. a full tank weighs the same no matter the load, so water weight shouldn't enter into the equation.

Comment: @jsotola: All washing machine mention a weight. The 7kg is the weight for the washing machine I have

Comment: @dandavis: The blanket if we put it in a tub of water it will absorb it and the weight will be more. My concern is if that weight would end up too much for the washing machine

Comment: @crip659: I am not sure what you are asking me. It is a normal washing machine for a household.

Comment: Dimensions are: 55.9 x 60 x 85 centimetres

Comment: https://inthewash.co.uk/washing-machines/washing-machine-capacity-wet-or-dry/#:~:text=This%20question%20has%20confused%20many,capacity%20refers%20to%20dry%20weight.  if it were wet weight, the thing couldn't even handle one pillow, as water weighs a kilo per liter.

Comment: @dandavis: Then since it is not even half the capacity the blanket should not cause an issue when wet right?

Comment: no problems. Virtually all washers with digital displays and soft-touch buttons should have over-load protections anyway, which would stop the cycle if a process was harder than expected to operate, before any damage was done. Even if it didn't trip a sensor, your only real issue is heat on the motor, and I don't think a one-time spike will cause issues in that dept. If you always ran it to the breaking point, things can deteriorate as motion in hot parts causes more wear than cool parts, but again, this is an occasional load...

Comment: Would figure dimensions should hold about 7kgs/15lbs of cloths.

Comment: Take it to a laundromat. That's what I do.

Comment: We've _never_ weighed laundry. A machine full of towels and/or blankets has never been an issue. I agree with @gnicko, though, if it doubt, take it to a laundromat with a _big_ machine.

Comment: Questions about appliance usage are specifically [off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Concerns about capability are still usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single item such as a blanket should present no issue on any modern machine.
The weight limit is dry weight, not wet.

On the wash cycle, there is absolutely no problem whatsoever, only as it starts to spin could there potentially be an issue. The spin wil start slowly & vari-speed once or twice as the machine measures the load distribution. It may try several times to check it can evenly distribute the weight inside the drum. Only when it's happy will it come up to full speed.
Even if it misjudged at this point, there should be a mechanism to pull it up if the weight goes badly out of balance. [This is amongst the reasons a washer needs to be level & on a hard surface - it helps this balance measurement].

Bad weight distribution tends to only be an issue with bulky items - pillows etc, where the weight is in 'one lump', or a duvet cover that manages to trap all the sheets inside itself [always fasten some of the buttons to prevent this]. A single blanket, though heavy, should be able to be spread itself out sufficiently by the spin mechanism before it gets up to speed.

Comment: I also have a duvet that although it is low small weight 2kg (while washing machine is 7kg) if I put it in it fills the drum fully, I have to press in to fit. I suppose it would not be a good idea at all to wash it there?

Comment: Never tried. Ours go to the cleaners. If you stand & watch it as it starts to spin you could intervene if it isn't having much fun ;)